# Why does my Regex stop a character short of where I'd expect?

Tags: php, regex

I'm playing around with a bit of text parsing basically with the idea of making a text format that supports variables and expressions and I'm running into a circumstance that doesn't make sense to me. I have the example text:

```
!BP1:VAR| The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.   
!BP2:VAR|Hello World!

Hey, do you know any good boilerplate text sayings?

How about '!BP1'?

Nice! I prefer the classic '!BP2' though.
```

and the regex:

```regex
!(?<var_use>[^\s:']+)[^:]
```

It can be seen in action [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xiwN07/1/)

I would expect it to match the second instance of !BP1 and !BP2 but not the first instances. Instead it matches the first instances but in a way I didn't expect. So it picks up 'BP' twice and then 'BP1' and 'BP2'. Instead of not matching at all it just shortens the capture group.

Here's some conceptual information. Basically, I'm declaring these variables, and then I want to pick up where they're used but not where they're declared.

How can I modify this to capture only the groups I want? If there are any insights as to why this regex works this way that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `!(?<var_use>[^\s:']++)(?!:)`, a possessive quantifier.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I wasn't quite sure what I was looking for in terms of asking the question and the cheat sheet I was looking at didn't make mention of the possessive quantifier along with the others.